# Touch Event Missed

Tags: android

Q. I am trying to capture touch events in code, they appear to work but do not catch the first touch of the screen?

Below is the log printout, it knows about the touch but its not allowing me to capture it? any help would be much appreciated.

I have included the code for the ontouch event, onCreate and the setViewFeatures:

At the top of the activity I have

```
    public class MediaActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, OnErrorListener,   OnInfoListener,
    OnPreparedListener, OnSeekCompleteListener, OnTouchListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setViewFeatures();

    setSessionData();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_media);



    setProgressBar();

    createPADialog();

    setDRMListeners();

    setClientAndServer();

    setButtonListeners();

    // Might use this for getting ref. for grabbing view when its first
    // displayed...
    // View v =
    // getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    try
    {

        setSurfaceView();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorLevel = ERRORS.CRITICAL;
        callError("UNABLE TO RUN MediaActivity", errorLevel);
    }

    }

    private void setViewFeatures()
    {


    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN 
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    int flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
              | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
              | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TOUCHABLE_WHEN_WAKING
              | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED 
              | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

    getWindow().addFlags(flags);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {

    Log.d("TAG", "In onTouch ");
    try
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            if (topBar.isOpened())
            {
                callCloseBars();
            }
            else
            {
                callOpenBars();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
    }

         return true;
    }


    10-14 07:33:09.900: I/InputReader(192): Touch event's action is 0x0 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=0.80 ]
    10-14 07:33:09.910: I/InputDispatcher(192): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
    10-14 07:33:09.910: I/InputDispatcher(192): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 0x0
    10-14 07:33:09.910: D/InputDispatcher(192): [drainOutboundQueueLocked] initialize cntPair(sender-receiver)
    10-14 07:33:09.910: I/InputQueue-JNI(192): Sending finished signal for input channel 'hidden nav  (client)' since it is being unregistered while an input message is still in progress.
    10-14 07:33:09.910: I/InputQueue-JNI(192): Ignoring finish signal on channel that is no longer registered.
    10-14 07:33:09.910: I/PowerManagerService(192): Ulight 3->7|0
    10-14 07:33:09.910: D/PowerManagerService(192): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 255
    10-14 07:33:10.060: D/Tethering(192): getTetheredIfacePairs
    10-14 07:33:10.080: I/InputReader(192): Touch event's action is 0x1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1,    pending(waiting finished signal)=0, s=]
```

Comment: It doesn't insert to the "onTouch" method at all in the first time? Where exatly in the code do you  call to the "OnTouchListener"?

Comment: I setup the mdiaplayer and surfaceview etc. then when I touch the screen it ignores it then when I touch again it responds by showing  the scrubber bar.

Comment: Can you add the "onCreate" Metod?

Comment: Added the on create and also the method for setting up various features for the view, cheers

Comment: Where did you call to the "SetOnTouchListener"?

Comment: I thought using the "implement" and then the override I did not need to call the inline setOnTouchListener - not sure what I would attach the setOnTouchListener to???

Comment: When exactly Do you want to go to the "OnTouch" method when the user touch on the layout? Button? TextView?

Comment: When the film starts playing, if the user touches the screen to see the scrubber bar - at present they have to touch twice to see the scrubber. So I really as soon as the screen is visible and the user touches the screen(view)

Comment: I added the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution if the listener called from the beginning(OnCreate):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener {
    View view;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     Log.d("TAG", "In onTouch ");
        try
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                i = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
    return true;
   }
}
```

In your code you can start the listening when the film start.

Comment: I had not put the setOnTouchListener for the surface view.  Cheers